# Confirming Password is still displaying "Passwords do not match" even when passwords do match

Tags: javascript, forms, passwords

So I am creating a signup form and I added password validation to make sure that both the password and confirm passwords match. The idea here is that while you initially type in your password, you are getting a **"Passwords do NOT match"**.

This is because you have not reentered your password in the confirm password input. Once you reenter it, and if it matches, then it should say **Passwords match!**. If it still does not match, the message should still say **Passwords do NOT match**.

The issue that I am having is that when the passwords do match initially, the message does not change to **Passwords match** it stays at **Passwords do NOT match**.

In order to get it to match, I have to go back to the password input, add a character, or remove a character, and then do the same for the confirm password. I have provided my code in the code snippet so that you can get a better visual of my explanation.

Does anyone know why this may be happening?

```js
  var passConfirm = function() {
         if (document.getElementById("Password").value ==
             document.getElementById("ConfirmPassword").value) {
             document.getElementById("Message").style.color = "Green";
             document.getElementById("Message").innerHTML = "Passwords match!"
        } else {
            document.getElementById("Message").style.color = "Red";
            document.getElementById("Message").innerHTML = "Passwords do NOT match!"
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <form class="form" onsubmit="validateForm(event)">
       <div>
            <label id="FullNameLabel">Full Name</label></br>
              <input 
                type="text" 
                placeholder="John Doe" 
                id="FullName">
            </input>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label id="EmailLabel">Email</label></br>
             <input 
                type="text" 
                placeholder="johndoe@email.com" 
                id="Email">
            </input>
         </div>
         <div>
            <label id="PhoneNumberLabel">Phone Number</label></br>
             <input 
                type="text" 
                placeholder="(123) 456-7890" 
                id="PhoneNumber">
            </input>
         </div>
         <div>
            <label id="PasswordLabel">Password</label></br>
             <input 
                name="Password"
                id="Password"
                type="password" 
                placeholder="Password"
                onkeyup='passConfirm();'>
            </input>
         </div>
         <div>
            <label id="ConfirmPswdLabel">Confirm Password</label></br>
             <input 
                type="password" 
                placeholder="Confirm Password" 
                id="ConfirmPassword"></input>
         </div>
         <span id="Message"></span>
      
    </form>
      <button type="submit" value="submit">Sign Me Up!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This is happening because you are calling password confirm function on Password input.
Call that function on confirm password input, onkeyup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that, you haven't added the `onKeyUp` event on the confirm password input. It works when you add. Also, use `<input />` and not `<input></input>`.

```js
var passConfirm = function() {
  if (document.getElementById("Password").value ==
    document.getElementById("ConfirmPassword").value) {
    document.getElementById("Message").style.color = "Green";
    document.getElementById("Message").innerHTML = "Passwords match!"
  } else {
    document.getElementById("Message").style.color = "Red";
    document.getElementById("Message").innerHTML = "Passwords do NOT match!"
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form class="form" onsubmit="validateForm(event)">
    <div>
      <label id="FullNameLabel">Full Name</label></br>
      <input type="text" placeholder="John Doe" id="FullName" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label id="EmailLabel">Email</label></br>
      <input type="text" placeholder="johndoe@email.com" id="Email" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label id="PhoneNumberLabel">Phone Number</label></br>
      <input type="text" placeholder="(123) 456-7890" id="PhoneNumber" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label id="PasswordLabel">Password</label></br>
      <input name="Password" id="Password" type="password" placeholder="Password" onkeyup='passConfirm();' />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label id="ConfirmPswdLabel">Confirm Password</label></br>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" id="ConfirmPassword" onkeyup='passConfirm();' />
    </div>
    <span id="Message"></span>
  </form>
  <button type="submit" value="submit">Sign Me Up!</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've added `onkeyup` event handler to only `Password` input.

You should track value changes for both password inputs to see if they are matched.

So adding `onkeyup='passConfirm();'` to `ConfirmPassword` input will solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

```js
  var passConfirm = function() {
         if (document.getElementById("Password").value ==
             document.getElementById("ConfirmPassword").value) {
             document.getElementById("Message").style.color = "Green";
             document.getElementById("Message").innerHTML = "Passwords match!"
        } else {
            document.getElementById("Message").style.color = "Red";
            document.getElementById("Message").innerHTML = "Passwords do NOT match!"
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <form class="form" onsubmit="validateForm(event)">
       <div>
            <label id="FullNameLabel">Full Name</label></br>
              <input 
                type="text" 
                placeholder="John Doe" 
                id="FullName">
            </input>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label id="EmailLabel">Email</label></br>
             <input 
                type="text" 
                placeholder="johndoe@email.com" 
                id="Email">
            </input>
         </div>
         <div>
            <label id="PhoneNumberLabel">Phone Number</label></br>
             <input 
                type="text" 
                placeholder="(123) 456-7890" 
                id="PhoneNumber">
            </input>
         </div>
         <div>
            <label id="PasswordLabel">Password</label></br>
             <input 
                name="Password"
                id="Password"
                type="password" 
                placeholder="Password"
                onkeyup='passConfirm();'>
            </input>
         </div>
         <div>
            <label id="ConfirmPswdLabel">Confirm Password</label></br>
             <input 
                type="password" 
                placeholder="Confirm Password" 
                id="ConfirmPassword"></input>
         </div>
         <span id="Message"></span>
      
    </form>
      <button type="submit" value="submit">Sign Me Up!</button>
</div>
```

```js
var passConfirm = function() {
  if (document.getElementById("Password").value ==
    document.getElementById("ConfirmPassword").value) {
    document.getElementById("Message").style.color = "Green";
    document.getElementById("Message").innerHTML = "Passwords match!"
  } else {
    document.getElementById("Message").style.color = "Red";
    document.getElementById("Message").innerHTML = "Passwords do NOT match!"
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form class="form" onsubmit="validateForm(event)">
    <div>
      <label id="FullNameLabel">Full Name</label></br>
      <input type="text" placeholder="John Doe" id="FullName" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label id="EmailLabel">Email</label></br>
      <input type="text" placeholder="johndoe@email.com" id="Email" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label id="PhoneNumberLabel">Phone Number</label></br>
      <input type="text" placeholder="(123) 456-7890" id="PhoneNumber" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label id="PasswordLabel">Password</label></br>
      <input name="Password" id="Password" type="password" placeholder="Password" onkeyup='passConfirm();' />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label id="ConfirmPswdLabel">Confirm Password</label></br>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" id="ConfirmPassword" onkeyup='passConfirm();' />
    </div>
    <span id="Message"></span>
  </form>
  <button type="submit" value="submit">Sign Me Up!</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
  var passConfirm = function() {
         if (document.getElementById("Password").value ==
             document.getElementById("ConfirmPassword").value) {
             document.getElementById("Message").style.color = "Green";
             document.getElementById("Message").innerHTML = "Passwords match!"
        } else {
            document.getElementById("Message").style.color = "Red";
            document.getElementById("Message").innerHTML = "Passwords do NOT match!"
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <form class="form" onsubmit="validateForm(event)">
       <div>
            <label id="FullNameLabel">Full Name</label></br>
              <input 
                type="text" 
                placeholder="John Doe" 
                id="FullName">
            </input>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label id="EmailLabel">Email</label></br>
             <input 
                type="text" 
                placeholder="johndoe@email.com" 
                id="Email">
            </input>
         </div>
         <div>
            <label id="PhoneNumberLabel">Phone Number</label></br>
             <input 
                type="text" 
                placeholder="(123) 456-7890" 
                id="PhoneNumber">
            </input>
         </div>
         <div>
            <label id="PasswordLabel">Password</label></br>
             <input 
                name="Password"
                id="Password"
                type="password" 
                placeholder="Password"
                onkeyup='passConfirm();'>
            </input>
         </div>
         <div>
            <label id="ConfirmPswdLabel">Confirm Password</label></br>
             <input 
                type="password" 
                placeholder="Confirm Password" 
                id="ConfirmPassword"></input>
         </div>
         <span id="Message"></span>
      
    </form>
      <button type="submit" value="submit">Sign Me Up!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).